# Inviscid Burgers equation — multivalued wave

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I'm quite new to Wolfram Mathematica. I need to create an animation of a Burgers Hopf equation's solution which becomes multivalued (somewhat of a breaking wave). Is it possible to do so in Mathematica?

All I seem to obtain is a very sharp series of oscillations which I assume are a numerical correction by the software.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
NDSolve[
  {D[u[x, t], t] + 1/2 D[u[x, t]^2, x] == 0, 
   u[x, 0] == Sech[x]^2, u[-5, t] == u[5, t]}, 
  u[x, t], {x, -5, 5}, {t, 0, 5}]`
```

Comment: There are examples of plots, even dynamic with Manipulate, on `NDSolve` documentation page. Have you seen them?

Comment: i have seen them but nothing seems to create the animation i need, which is a c-
shaped wave

Comment: I don't think you can get c-shaped wave, nor wiki page shows them. But you create a steep one with your solution.

Comment: What do you mean by c-shaped wave? Can you be more specific?

Comment: i mean an animation of a gaussian like wave in which the upper portion goes faster tham the lower one, so it creates sort of a breaking wave, but kuba confirmed my suspects, it's probably  not possible to obtain in Mathematica

Comment: It is not about MMA but the equation: `With[{uu = 
   NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, t], t] + 1/2 D[u[x, t]^2, x] == 0, 
     u[x, 0] == Sech[x]^2, u[-5, t] == u[5, t]}, 
    u, {x, -5, 5}, {t, 0, 5}]
  },
 Animate[Plot[uu[x, t], {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {-.5, 2}], {t, 0, 5}]
 ]`.

Comment: You mean something like this?: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sgVos.png

Comment: xzczd yes but the peak should move above the lower part and create somewhat of a c

Comment: [link](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Appearance-of-multistream-flows-in-the-Hopf-equation_fig1_225104451)

Answer (score 7):

I don't think `NDSolve` is the right tool for the task, because it can only solve for single-valued functions. (Well, is there any mathematical software that can deal with multi-valued functions natively? ) Fortunately, your goal is just creating an animation for the multi-valued solution, then we can simply refer to the [analytic solution of this problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation#Solution_of_inviscid_Burgers'_equation):

```
Animate[ParametricPlot[{t f[ξ] + ξ, f[ξ]}, {ξ, -5, 5}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio], {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much :)